# IBM Worklight - Project built on 6.1 will not deploy on 6.1 server, says I need to use 6.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-server

I've got a very simple Worklight application, no adapters, no java code, just some HTML. It's built in Eclipse Juno with Worklight studio 6.1. When I try to deploy the *-all.wlapp file the worklight server (not the worklight studio server, but an actual WL server running in a WebSphere cluster) I get the following message:

```
Failed to deploy application 'XXXX-all.wlapp'. The 'application' version '6.1.0.00.20131219-1900' is different than the version of the Worklight project '6.0.0'. Use Worklight Studio '6.0.0' to build and deploy the application.
```

The project was created using Worklight studio 6.1 and has never seen the 6.0 studio. What's wrong with this thing that it wants me to back-rev to 6.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This likely means you did not update the project's `war` file on the application server.

While the Worklight Server instance deployed to the application server is of v6.1, it is running a Worklight 6.0-based "project", while your `wlapp` was created with v6.1.

Deploy a newer .war file based on v6.1 of the same project followed by re-deployment of the `wlapp`.

Comment: When I do 'about' on the work light console I get this for the additional support info: Server version: 6.1.0.00.20131126-0630
Project WAR version: 6.0.0   Is it an administrative action to update the Project WAR version or is that done from the WL studio?

Comment: mmm, no. I would say more of an IT task to update the server with a newer .war.

Comment: I see now what needs to be done. The .WAR file generated by the WL studio in my project needs to get deployed as a Enterprise application in WebSPhere, replacing the old Enterprise application that was there before when we did an earlier proof-of-concept with Worklight.